# Get another user's username from user id - Parse & Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform, sinch

I've been trying to make a simple instant messaging application for iOS and Android. Got it all done on iOS. I'm stuck on one thing on Android though.

Whenever I send a message, it sends the message with the two objects `sender` and `other`. Sender is, well, the sender of the message, and other is the person receiving the message.

On iOS, it gives `sender` the username of the currently logged in user. Same thing with `other`, but it gives it the username of the person receiving the message. On Android, currently, I can only get it to give `sender` the user*name* of the currently logged in user, and `other` is set to the user *id* of the person receiving the message. I want to get Android to set `other` to a username.

I'm very novice with Java and Android app development. I know a lot more with Swift and iOS development. I'm pretty sure, though, that doing this would require a query.

Can someone give me a pointer on how to do this? Thanks so much!

Code:
[Pastebin #1](http://pastebin.com/2jP1DJEu)
[Pastebin #2](http://pastebin.com/V0d5y2R3)
*StackOverflow won't let me put in another link. I can just paste it in a reply if someone wants to look at it.*

p.s. Sorry if this doesn't make too much sense. I don't really know how to describe it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about sinch (looks like you're using this service to do the messaging?), I can see that the `other` variable is being set via an intent extra when you're creating the `MessagingActivity`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        Intent intent = getIntent();
       // recipientId = intent.getStringExtra("RECIPIENT_ID");
        other = intent.getStringExtra("OTHER"); 
        ...

    };
```

I would be looking at what extra (named "OTHER") you're adding to the intent in whatever activity calls the MessagingActivity intent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most clear but if you look in the ios tutorial, you start the sinch client with  the username, not the parse user id

```
[initSinchClient:self.usernameField.text];
```

But in the android app you start it with the parse userid

```
currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        currentUserName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername();

        if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
            startSinchClient(currentUserId); //change this 
        }
```

try changing this to 
                startSinchClient(currentUserName);

Answer (score 0):

You should make a Parse Query if you want to get the userName of the receiver from his userId:

Try the following:

```
String receiverName = null;
List<ParseUser> users = null;
try {
ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
userQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", other);
users = userQuery.find();
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
if( users != null && users.size() >= 1)
{receiverName = users.get(0).getUsername();}
```

Comment: Woo! Thanks so far. I'm definitely getting somewhere. However, I get an error on `List<ParseUser> users = userQuery.find();`. The error is: Error:(56, 47) error: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown. What's going on here? Thanks!!

Comment: Just tried this. This time I'm getting two errors. One is on `String receiverName = users.get(0).getUsername();` and the error message is `Not a statement`. The other one is the same as before, on `userQuery.find();` and the message is `Unhanded exception: com.parse.ParseException`.

Comment: Add accolade like this if( users != null && users.size() >= 1) {String receiverName = users.get(0).getUsername();} For the second, you should be able to handle the ParseException by clicking on the error. On which IDE you are working? I edited the answer! Hope it helps

Comment: Alright got those two errors sorted out. The second error was actually very easy to fix (I forgot to import com.parse.ParseException) and I'm not getting any errors inside of Android Studio. However, now, whenever I try to send a message (inside of the app), the app crashes. ("Unfortunately, [appname] has stopped.") Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: I think you get a nullPointerException somewhere. Can I take a look at your code?

Comment: Check out my [GitHub](https://github.com/insleep/swiff-android/) for all of the code.

Comment: In your code, the "other" attribute will always be null because you never affect a value to it then you try to send a message like this:  messageService.sendMessage(other, messageBody); but "other" is null. It should represent the Id of the recipient. Try to have a look at the official tutorial here: https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/

Comment: The official tutorial is where I actually got the code from. I've only changed a few things. I don't remember them mentioning how to convert an id to a username in there..

Comment: There is no necessity to convert UserId to UserName to make your app working. But to send a message, you should provide a recipient Id! does that sound clear?

Comment: There is a necessity to convert it..the reason why I want to do this is because the iOS version does this (Swift coding language) and I want to be able to see iOS-sent messages from the Android app, if that makes sense. (The iOS app sets the sender to the sender's username, not userId and the same thing with who it's being sent to (recipient), and before, the Android app set those both to objectId's, but then I was able to change it so the sender is a username, not a userId but I still can't get the recipient to change from a userid to a username. Sorry if this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I understand what you want to do. In the tutorial, you have a "ListUsersActivity" which displays the list of all users. When you click on a user item, the "MessagingActivity" is opened and you can send a message to this user by calling send function. Note that in onClick Method under ListUsersActivity, the recipient is sent to MessagingActivity by using "intent.putExtra", then in onCreate under MessagingActivity, you can get it by using: Intent intent = getIntent(); recipientId = intent.getStringExtra("RECIPIENT_ID");

Comment: So what you can do is to put the attribute "other" as hard-coded!